# What is the best way to wait until a frame is loaded in QTP?

Tags: automated-tests, qtp

In Web addin QTP provides **Sync** function for Browser and Page objects in order to wait until the correposponding navigation is complete.

Although, there is no such a function for a Frame.

What is the best way to wait until the frame content is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait on the [ready state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534359.aspx)  (4 is **complete**).

```
Browser("...").Page("...").Frame("...").WaitProperty "state", 4
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried what you suggested. It doesn't work in my case. readyState value is 4, but frame content is still not loaded.
Most likely it happens because frame content is loaded by a javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,
pivot =0
do
If (Browser("...").Page("...").Frame("...").Getroproperty("abs_x")) Then
'do the next operations
  pivot = 1
End if
while (pivot =0)

'the syntax is incorrect!